# Subscript out of range in VBA when trying to use an array

Tags: excel, vba

Please could you help - i currently get a subscript out of range error when the vba gets to "tb.sheets(shName).copy" & i cant figure out why - any support would be appreciated! Thank you

```
    Sub Create_Consolidated_File()

Dim tB As Excel.Workbook
Dim wB As Excel.Workbook
Dim ExportArray As Variant
Dim ShName As Variant
Dim ExportName As String

Dim varResult As Variant

Dim Attachments As Range
Set Attachments = Range("D3:E28")



For Each Row In Attachments
    For Each cell In Row

Set tB = ThisWorkbook
ExportArray = Array(cell.Value) 'work on this bit to define as the sheet names in columns D & E

For Each ShName In ExportArray
    tB.Sheets(ShName).Copy
```

Comment: Because the current **ShName** value is not the valid name of a sheet in the current workbook. Put the cursor over ShName to see what the value is.

Comment: Thank you paul - if i hover over it it say 41077 which is the name of a sheet in the workbook - is there any issue with is being a number as opposed to a word by any chance?

Comment: Excel accepts numeric sheets name, but it can see them in different ways: `Sheets(1)` means the first sheet of the workbook (using its index). `Sheets("1")` means the sheet **named as 1** (using its name). So, you need to convert the number as String. Using `CStr`, placing double quotes at its extremities or simple declare it `Dim ShName As String`, format the cell keeping the number as Text etc.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? 3 nested *For Each...Next* loops seem rather inefficient. By merely using a variable named `Row`, VBA will not know to loop through rows and will probably loop through the cells and then will again loop through the cells of the single cell writing each to the array and loop through the single worksheet...etc. If you're trying to return each row (each cell contains a sheet name?) in an array, use e.g. `For Each Row In Attachments.Rows: ExportArray = Row.Value: For Each shName In ExportArray: tb.Sheets(CStr(shName)).Copy: ' Continue... :Next shName: Next Row`.

Answer (score 2):

If the sheet name is numeric, then convert it to a string with CStr.
I also added some syntax to complete the code you provided.

```
Sub Create_Consolidated_File()
    
    Dim tB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ExportArray As Variant
    Dim ShName As Variant
    Dim ExportName As String
    
    Dim varResult As Variant
    
    Dim Attachments As Range
    Set Attachments = Range("D3:E28")
    
    
    
    For Each Row In Attachments
        For Each cell In Row
    
        Set tB = ThisWorkbook
        ExportArray = Array(cell.Value) 'work on this bit to define as the sheet names in columns D & E
    
        For Each ShName In ExportArray
            Debug.Print (ShName)
            tB.Sheets(CStr(ShName)).Copy
        Next
    Next
    Next
    
    End Sub
```